Keep getting error when importing tensorflow in my file
I have this code in python  where I need to use Tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16, preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model


class FeatureExtractor:
    def __init__(self):
        base_model = VGG16(weights="imagenet")
        self.model = Model(
            inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer("fc1").output
        )


and I keep getting this error Import "tensorflow.keras.preprocessing" could not be resolved
Could anyone give me any advice on how to fix this?
I have already installen tensorflow by typing pip install tensorflow in my terminal and when I checked if it has installed I got this
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.16.2
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\Users\37360\Documents\SearchEngine.venv\Lib\site-packages
Requires: tensorflow-intel
Required-by:
I have seen an article where it said that some versions of Python and Tensorflow are incompetible but I would still like to know how to fix it. Thank you in advance for answering my question.
enter image description here
I have tried:
1.pip install tensorflow
2.pip install tensorflow==2.16.2
3.pip install --upgrade tensorflow
4.pip uninstall tensorflow
5.pip install tensorflow

If you open a python shell, what do you got by typing "import tensorflow"? Also, follow the uffical guide and do the check from the offical page https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Are you working with a virtual environment (e.g. venv), and did you install the package to that virtual environment?

I am using venv

I fixed it. Just enable your Pylance and run it again. As simple as that. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.
